# Why is my Forio Contour chart's legend rotated?

Tags: forio-contour

I have a simple line chart using Forio Contour with two series. When I turn on the legend, it appears in the chart area as a box with correct info, but the box is rotated about -80 degrees -- totally tilted to the left. 
I go through some steps below using the Contour data connectors with sample csv data because my real data will be imported in csv format. I'm not sure if this is related to the problem. Any ideas about why the legend is so askew?
Thank you, Carrie

```
<body>
    <div style="text-align:left;">
      <div id="companySalesGraph"  class="companySalesGraph" style="width:700;height:300px;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
  <script>
      var csvData1 = 'quarter,cost,revenue,profit\n2013Q1,100,150,50\n2013Q2,110,150,40\n2013Q3,90,180,90\n2013Q4,105,190,85';
      var csv = new Contour.connectors.Csv(csvData1);   
      var data =  csv.dimension('quarter').measure('revenue');
      var data2 = csv.dimension('quarter').measure('profit');
      var data3 = data.concat(data2);
      var chart = new Contour({
        el: '.companySalesGraph',
        xAxis: { title: 'Quarter' },
        yAxis: { title: '$K' }
      })
        .cartesian()
        .line(data3)
        .legend(data3)
        .tooltip()
        .render();
    </script>
```

PS, I tried using these custom settings, which did relocate the legend, but it was still rotated

```
legend: {
            vAlign: 'top',
            hAlign: 'left'

        }
```

Comment: Hi Carrie, Can you tell me what version of Contour are you using? (Just do Contour.version from the console), also do you have any other styles being imported/applied to the page?

Comment: Hi Jaime, Contour version is "0.9.84". I created a test page and stripped out all the other code and styles, and the legend is not rotated. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction! I'll dig in and see if I can figure out where the conflict is.  Carrie

Comment: Glad to hear your on the right track now, when you figure it out, I'd be curious to know what was happening.

Comment: We had a 'vertical' class in our own css file, which was being applied to the legend... must be a 'vertical' class in one of the Contour built-in styles? We renamed our class and all is good. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out a previously defined style in my project was being applied to the Contour legend, presumably because of duplicate class names. When I renamed my class, the problem went away.